# How to parse email body without previous conversation ?

Tags: regex, python-2.7, parsing

In gmail when we conversation with others then at the end each email concatenate with previous conversation. by the help of python **imaplib** library i get the email body like below . Now i want to delete previous conversation and get only main message...

**Input:**

```
--------------------Now i Have--------------------------
Dear vaia,


Sale order fail to sync when it contain Generic Product. ....need to little
investigate about it.
This is a issue which is occurred if any product have salePrice of greated
then 2 decimal value like 33.34500 etc.
Now POS only use @ decimal values like 33.34 so please aware about this
about configuring prism to have always 2 decimal digits.


On Thu, Jan 26, 2017 at 9:23 PM, Abu Shaed Rimon <rimon@divine-it.net>
wrote:

>
> Dear Concern,
>
> Observation after update:-
>
> -- "+" sign working for add customer and Product but this button also
>
> Thank You.
>
>
> *...Best Regards,*
> http://www.divineit.net
>
>
> On Thu, Jan 26, 2017 at 5:44 PM, Khirun Nahar Urmi <urmi@divine-it.net>
> wrote:
>
>> Dear Rimon vaia,
>>
>>
>> Please take an update from git
>>
>> On Thu, Jan 26, 2017 at 3:24 PM, Abu Shaed Rimon <rimon@prismerp.net>
>> wrote:
>>
>>> Dear Concern,
>>>
>>> Please take a review about the mentioned observation in following :-
>>> *Helpdesk:* http://support.divineit.net
>>>
```

**Output:**

```
---------------------My Expectation-------------------------
Dear vaia,


Sale order fail to sync when it contain Generic Product. ....need to little
investigate about it.
This is a issue which is occurred if any product have salePrice of greated
then 2 decimal value like 33.34500 etc.
Now POS only use @ decimal values like 33.34 so please aware about this
about configuring prism to have always 2 decimal digits.
```

Comment: Have you tried writing any code? You can select only the lines that do not start with an `>`.

Comment: Use regex to match something like *"On Thu, Jan 26, 2017 at 9:23 PM, Abu Shaed Rimon <rimon@divine-it.net> wrote:"* and stop when you reach it?

Comment: if the message body contain '>' then that line is missing. @yper

Comment: You can use `startswith()` function. You can iterate from the last line up and when you encounter a line that does not start with `>`, stop the process and take all the lines above.

Comment: 'On Thu, Jan 26, 2017 at 9:23 PM, Abu Shaed Rimon <rimon@divine-it.net> wrote:' is dynamic for different conversation thread and time @jonrsharpe

Comment: then it contain 'On Thu, Jan 26, 2017 at 9:23 PM, Abu Shaed Rimon <rimon@divine-it.net>
wrote:'  but i want to delete this line... i want better option and lower complexity @yper

Comment: (adding to my previous message) + not include 2 or 3 lines above the highest `<` line.

Comment: Yes, that's why you use a regex to match the *shape* of it rather than comparing the specific *value*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it like so:

```
import re

with open(file, 'r') as f:
    print re.findall(r'^.*?(?=On \w{3},)', f.read(), re.DOTALL)[0].strip()
```

Output:

```
Dear vaia,


Sale order fail to sync when it contain Generic Product. ....need to little
investigate about it.
This is a issue which is occurred if any product have salePrice of greated
then 2 decimal value like 33.34500 etc.
Now POS only use @ decimal values like 33.34 so please aware about this
about configuring prism to have always 2 decimal digits.
```

Regex:

`^.*?(?=On \w{3},)` - Match everything from starting till first occurence of `On \w{3},` pattern.

`re.DOTALL` will make the `.` match newline characters as well.

Comment: the RE dose not work.... please check https://regex101.com/r/1dhmZH/1 @MYGz

Comment: @masumbillah  You did not turn on the single line flag. Anyways I have tested the code. Did you test it?

Comment: @masumbillah  You need to switch off the multiline flag and switch on the single line flag.

Comment: @masumbillah  please check the regex101 link I have mentioned in the previous comment. The regex is working.

Comment: @masumbillah  v1 is yours. v2 is mine. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: if the message can not contain 'On' then it return empty and on the body it contain "On The, Jun you come to my office" it return something that is error @MYGz

Comment: Then you can extend the look ahead further `(?=On \w{3}, \w{3} \d{1,2}, \d{4})`

Comment: brilient works But if you can add next line starts with '>' i think then it works better

Comment: @masumbillah  If it works then perhaps consider accepting the answer.

Comment: @Edulynch I restricted `\w{3}` for a reason, please don't edit like that. Your edit would have failed the regex.